# How to get displacement field or control point vector when we have tfrom?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-registration

I am using image registration toolbox to register two 3D images. I register the moving image to the fixed image. I use "imregtform" to save tform.

```
tform = imregtform(moving,fixed,transformType,optimizer,metric)
```

for example this is my 'tform':

```
    1.0235    0.0022   -0.0607         0
   -0.0276    1.0002    0.0089         0
   -0.0170   -0.0141    1.1685         0
   12.8777    5.0311  -70.0325    1.0000
```

then I use 'Imwarp' to transfer moving image to the fixed image. In my code it is,

```
nii=load_untouch_nii(['mypath image.nii' ]);
I = nii.img; 
dii=nii.hdr.dime.pixdim(2:4);
Rfixed=imref3d(size(I),dii(2),dii(1),dii(3)); 
timg= imwarp(I, Rfixed, tform, 'OutputView', Rfixed);
```

'timg' is transfered image of source image.I checked it and it is working fine, but I need control points or displacement field of this transformation now. In another word, I need to know each voxel(3d pixel) moved to which position. If I know this I can draw vector field. In deformable image registartion methods such as [NiftyReg package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/niftyreg/), control point command is provided to make it easy for users but I do not know how to do it in simple 3d affine in Matlab. 
Any help will be appreciated too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your geometric transform to a single point very easily.

You just need to have your point defined as `p=[x;y;z;1]`

and then obtain `pt` by `pt=p*tform;` `pt=pt(1:3)./pt(4);` (search for homogeneous coordinates for explanation of this last division). This is what `imwarp` does in the inside. It performs the said multiplication for each pixel `p`.

To then obtain the displacement, you would need just to `disp=pt-p;`. Note that the displacements are most likely not integer.

Note that in the field of deformable image registration, generally you will have a different `tform` for each control point (that is why it is called deformable and not rigid)

**EDIT**: as @Ashish Uthama suggests in the comments, you can also do it with Matlab inbuilt function `transformpointsforward()`. I will always be a promoter of "writing your own code" philosophy, specially the first time, so you do understand what are you actually doing.

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine3d.transformpointsforward.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply, it seems working. I want to apply it to simple grid.  
`[U, V, W] = ndgrid(336, 166,336); p = [100;70;110;1]; pt=pt(1:3)./pt(4); ` the result is `   -0.0158
   -0.0113
   -0.0208`, so this is displacement or control point?

Comment: I called it `pt` as "point transformed". The displacement would be `disp=pt-p;` @Ehsan

Comment: Also: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine3d.transformpointsforward.html :)

Comment: Thanks for both of you, i know what is going behind and what is matlab function now. Regards

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have implemented based on what you said, but the result of my code is not same as imwarp. Can you look at [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437467/how-imwarp-transfer-points-in-matlab) ? Thanks.

Comment: @AshishUthama I have problem with `transformpointsforward` because in my case my result is not match with imwarp result. any help ? Thanks