# How imwarp transfer points in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-registration

I am using Matlab to transform an image to target image. I have geometric transformation(tform).

for example this is my 'tform':

```
    1.0235    0.0022   -0.0607         0
   -0.0276    1.0002    0.0089         0
   -0.0170   -0.0141    1.1685         0
   12.8777    5.0311  -70.0325    1.0000
```

In Matlab2013, it is possible to do it easily using imwarp:

```
%nii = 3D MR Image
I = nii.img; 
dii=nii.hdr.dime.pixdim(2:4);
Rfixed=imref3d(size(I),dii(2),dii(1),dii(3));    
new_img= imwarp(old_img, Rfixed, tform, 'OutputView', Rfixed);
```

the result is perfect using imwarp (red lung in the image)

[image]

I need to know how imwarp is working, Then I wrote my own function

```
function [new_img] = aff3d(old_img, tform, range_x, range_y, range_z)

   [U, V, W] = ndgrid(range_x, range_y, range_z);
   xyz = [reshape(U,[],1)';reshape(V,[],1)';reshape(W,[],1)'];
   xyz = [xyz; ones(1,size(xyz,2))];


   uvw = tform.T * xyz;
   % avoid homogeneous coordinate  
   uvw = uvw(1:3,:)';


   xi = reshape(uvw(:,1), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));
   yi = reshape(uvw(:,2), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));
   zi = reshape(uvw(:,3), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));

   old_img = single(old_img);
   new_img = interp3(old_img,yi,xi,zi,'linear');

   ii = find(isnan(new_img));
   if(~isempty(ii))
      new_img(ii) = 0;
   end
end
```

[image]

the result of my function ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240436/how-to-get-displacement-field-or-control-point-vector-when-we-have-tfrom)) is not match with imwarp output ( red lung is not locating in a correct place), anybody can help me?

Comment: "I need to know how imwarp is working" how about looking at its implementation? `open imwarp` shows the source code

Comment: @m.s. I did but main functions are Mex file and I cannot see the code

Comment: Try multiplying by inv(TFORM . T)

Comment: @AnderBiguri not working by inv. I am thinking why imwarp of Matlab needs  `imref3d`. There is something inside that i dont know. is my method implemented wrong?

Comment: Try uvw=uvw(1:3,:)'./uvw(4,:)

Comment: @AnderBiguri i lose the image if I divide it. the dimension of above command is not correct but I can do `uvw = uvw(1:3,:)' ./ [uvw(4,:); uvw(4,:); uvw(4,:)]'; ` but as  I said it is not working too. im disappointed now.

Comment: What does tform. T returns if called in the command window ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri  `tform.T` returns like the example (4x4 matrix) that i have shown above, tform is a structure. and geometric transformation matrix is in tform.T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78702/discussion-between-ehsan-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: I just found this, maybe its a key ,http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/67114-what-is-the-difference-between-imwarp-and-imtransform

Comment: Could you share why you would want to do exactly what imwarp already does for you? I assume there are all sorts of padding/boundary issues that the mex file takes care of for you, it would not be trivial to try reproducing all that numerics exactly.

Comment: @Ahish good question, I need motion field and as you said before i used transformationpointforward function. But the motion  i take from that function is different from imwarp result. I need to know how exactly imwarp working to get the correct motion field. Since by using imwarp my transformation looks perfect. Thanks

Comment: One last comment, the source for IMWARP IS available. The only functions that are compiled MEX are the interpolation routines. Everything else is in MATLAB. Conceptually, you should be able to review all aspects of the IMWARP implementation by stepping through the MATLAB code as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was suggested by Ander, try multiplying by the inverse transformation:

```
Tinv = tform.invert();
TinvMatrix = Tinv.T;
```

So your code would become:

```
function [new_img] = aff3d(old_img, tform, range_x, range_y, range_z)
   [U, V, W] = ndgrid(range_x, range_y, range_z);
   xyz = [reshape(U,[],1)';reshape(V,[],1)';reshape(W,[],1)'];
   xyz = [xyz; ones(1,size(xyz,2))];

   tformInv = invert(tform);
   uvw = tformInv.T * xyz;
   % avoid homogeneous coordinate  
   uvw = uvw(1:3,:)';
   xi = reshape(uvw(:,1), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));
   yi = reshape(uvw(:,2), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));
   zi = reshape(uvw(:,3), length(range_x),length(range_y),length(range_z));
   old_img = single(old_img);
   new_img = interp3(old_img,yi,xi,zi,'linear');
   ii = find(isnan(new_img));
   if(~isempty(ii))
      new_img(ii) = 0;
   end
end
```

In your code, you are interpolating within the old_img to try to find the new_img which has been warped. This implies that what you want to do is use the inverse mapping that maps from the output image space to the input image space. You appear to be interpolating your old image using the forward mapping of points, which is incorrect.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/04/28/spatial-transforms-forward-mapping/
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/05/05/spatial-transformations-inverse-mapping/

I would use the above links to review forward vs. inverse mapping. IMWARP uses inverse mapping.

Part of the reason for confusion is that when people think of geometric transformations, they generally think in terms of the forward mapping of how points map from the old_image to the new_image. For this reason, the "T" property of the affine3d transformation is phrased in terms of the forward mapping.

When geometric transformations need to be implemented in software, it's much easier/better to implement things in terms of the inverse mapping. That is what imwarp does, and that's why you need to invert the transformation while you are trying to reproduce the imwarp behavior. If you read the blog post on inverse mapping, this algorithm is exactly what IMWARP is doing.

The only wrinkle you will need to work through is what IMWARP does in non-default coordinate systems (using non-default spatial referencing objects) in the case where the WorldLimits are not evenly divisible by the discrete grid of pixels. This behavior is arbitrary, there is no "right" behavior. The IMWARP behavior is to to honor the requested resolution (PixelExtentInWorld) and to slightly adjust the world limits in this case.

Comment: I have inversed Tform as @Ander and you said, but the image is not still matching with imwarp. It may because of world coordinate system. I used matlab source code and I solved my problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: The insight about the inverse mapping vs forward mapping was very helpful, thanks a lot!